# bind variable and shell scripting with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, scripting, sqlplus

I wish to execute DMLs using bind variable with shell scripts.
For example, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

SH_NUM=10

sqlplus -S test_user/test_pass <<EOD
var a number;
a:=${SH_NUM}
insert into test_table values(a);
commit;
EOD
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, I can use this approch when using pl/sql but I wish to know if I can do it this method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash

SH_NUM=10

sqlplus -S bp/bp<<EOD
set lines 220 pages 5000
col plan_table_output format a50
var a number;
exec :a :=${SH_NUM};
insert into t1 values(:a);
commit;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'basic'));
exit
EOD
```

Execute it (I just put `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR` in there to see the last statement executed):

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ./1.sh

1 row created.


Commit complete.


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------
EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:
------------------------
insert into t1 values(:a)


-----------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name |
-----------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |      |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | T1   |
-----------------------------------------


12 rows selected.
```

Comment: Well, it does completed without error, however `select * from t1` returns 0 rows..

Comment: @Nir I beg to differ: https://pastebin.com/Ny7gWh7g

Comment: Can you `select *` and not `count(*)` as values are sent empty. I double checked and row count does increasing but values are empty string (or null).

Comment: Solution: change `a` assignment to `exec :a := ${SH_NUM};`

Comment: I think `a=${SH_NUM}` will not do what you expect because `a` is the append command of the sqlplus editor. The correct command is `exec  :a:=3` or`begin :a:=3; end;`

Comment: @Nir Indeed, fixed.